# Perl regex: how to match strings that have a digit in between two nondigits?

Tags: regex, string, perl

How do I match strings of an array that has one or more digits in between two nondigits, and the string ends with a digit? Let's say I wanted to print out the strings that *didn't* match. How would I do this?

Here's what I have so far

```
my @array = ("OST3GIC2", "GRE1", "foo23eoo4","MAX13", "foo9fsa2");
foreach @array{
if !(grep /^+\D(+\d)+\D\d$/) {
print $_."\n";
}
```

**Desired Output**

```
GRE1
MAX13
```

thanks

Comment: The quantifier (`+`) goes *after* the character class, not before it. This regex you have could never have compiled without errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could look for:

```
/\D\d+\D.*\d$/
```

- `\D` non-digit
- `\d+` any number of digits
- `\D` a non-digit
- `.*` anything
- `\d` a digit
- `$` finally end-of-string

Answer (score 2):

If you want the non-matches directly, you can use

```
^\D+\d+$
```

If you want the matches, and then filter out, you can use

```
^\D*\d+\D+\d+$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my @array = ("OST3GIC2", "GRE1", "foo23eoo4","MAX13", "foo9fsa2");

print(join("\n", grep { ! /^\D+\d+\D+\d+$/ } @array) . "\n");
```

Meaning

- `!` to inverse the regexp result
- `^\D\d+\D+\d+$` means *start* with any non digit, then any digits, then any non digits, then *ends* with digits

( *any* means at least one here )